# Unit of work repository pattern for static class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

Task assigned to me is to refactor a code but should't modify static access modifier of class. I am trying to implement service layer , unit of work , repository pattern . static repository code is below , how can i implement unit of work and repository pattern for a static class? i like to implement a solution applying solid principles and unit testable application.

static class

```
 using System;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;

  namespace Contoso
  {
    public static class UsersRepository
    {
        private static string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(local);    Database=Users;User Id=sa;Password=password;";

        public static User Load(int userId)
        {
            User user = new User();

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = " + userId,
                connection);
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                user.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                user.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(reader["DateOfBirth"].ToString());
                user.Country = reader["Country"].ToString();
            }

            connection.Close();

            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should ask this question at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think this is a good 'how do I...?' question to ask that doesn't necessarily fall under code review.  While creating UOWs is most often done in an instantiated context, there's no real reason you can't have a static UOW pattern.  Unconventional does not mean incorrect or even impossible.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i implement unit of work and repository pattern for a static class?

You can leverage the fact that whenever someone calls the code here, they do so via a **public entry point**. This means that when the caller first enters the class (via said public method), you create a unit of work and dispose of it only when that same method returns a value to the caller (or simply ends).

Something along the lines of:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static User LoadUser(int userId)
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            DoSomething(uow);

            var user = uow.UserRepository.GetById(userId);

            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, every public method should create, use and dispose of a single unit of work instance. This ensures two things:

- Concurrent calls use their own separate unit of work.
- No unit of work will ever linger in-memory after the entry method has finished.

This does get trickier when you start using async programming, but I'm omitting that consideration since you never mentioned it either.

---

> i like to implement a solution applying solid principles and unit testable application

It gets slightly trickier when you deal with dependency injection. Static classes do not have an injectable constructor (note: they do have a constructor, but they don't allow for constructor arguments).

So injecting your dependency is going to be... atypical. One solution I can think of is to explicitly set the kernel (I am using NInject here as a matter of example):

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static IKernel Kernel { get; set; }

    public static User LoadUser(int userId)
    {
        using (var uow = Kernel.Get<IUnitOfWork>())
        {
            DoSomething(uow);

            var user = uow.UserRepository.GetById(userId);

            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

How you set the kernel (either by setting it explicitly or assigning it a default value directly) is up to you.

Without NInject or any similar library, you could achieve dependency injection using a `Func<IUnitOfWork>` as your factory method to create a unit of work on demand:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static Func<IUnitOfWork> CreateUnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public static User LoadUser(int userId)
    {
        using (var uow = CreateUnitOfWork())
        {
            DoSomething(uow);

            var user = uow.UserRepository.GetById(userId);

            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

Again, how you set the factory method's content is up to you, e.g.:

```
MyClass.CreateUnitOfWork = () => new UnitOfWork();
```

Comment: Excellent solution.  The team I'm working on tends to abuse static classes to a certain extent, but I'm unwilling to throw out the idea of a static UOW pattern out of hand - sooner or later, any real-world situation can lead to using any two ideas together.  I'm not certain that static UOW is an _optimal_ way to do UOW, and would recommend a more instantiated approach whenever possible, but if nothing else the idea of a static UOW pattern is a great coding exercise that makes the most of static classes.